# js on click wait, then post form

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to submit a form with ONClick. However, I would like the Onclick to wait 1 second before proceeding with the submit. I tried to implement this, but the form is not submitting at all now.

CODE:
http://pastebin.com/enhL8XwN
(can't post code directly, SO won't submit the question)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are binding the event to the form click event. Try adding another button and attach the event to it.

```
<form action="voteupdate.php" id="form-id" method="post">  
  <input type="hidden" name="type" id="type" value="' . $type . '">  
  <input type="hidden" name="id" id="id" value="' . $id . '">  
  <div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">  
    <label class="btn btn-default '.$vup.'">  
        <input type="radio" name="vote" id="1" value="1">  
     <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-up"></span> Vote up  
     </label>  
    <label class="btn btn-default '.$vd.'">  
        <input type="radio" name="vote" id="2" value="2">  
   <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down"></span> Vote down    
    </label>    
  </div>
  <input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="setTimeout(function(){ document.getElementById('form-id').submit(); }, 1000)" />


</form>
```

Comment: Sorry, there is an extra `}` at the end of onclick just before the `"`. remove it as I updated the code.